Prime between $p$ and $2p$
If $p$ is an odd prime, then by Bertrand's postulate, there is a prime $q$ (strictly) between $p$ and $2p$.
We bisect the interval $[p,2p]$ as $[p,\frac{3}{2}p] \cup [\frac{3}{2}p,2p]$.
Q. Are there any known results such as -

the prime $q$ between $p$ and $2p$ can always be found in first half interval $[p,\frac{3}{2}p]$ except for finitely many $p$; or

the prime $q$ between $p$ and $2p$ can always be found in second half interval $[\frac{3}{2}p,2p]$ except for finitely many $p$.



(I am not familiar with basic number theory dealing with such type of questions, so my question may be elementary.)
Bertrand's postulate is proved for any $n\ge 1$ instead of assuming it to be prime; but I am looking specific case.

Adding the tag [tag:analytic-number-theory] because users with expertise in that area are best placed to give good answers. Anyway, I think the error bounds to the prime counting function are sharp enough to prove both the claims. I think the result holds for any $\alpha>1$ in place of $3/2$, but the number of small exceptions (though finite) will blow up as $\alpha\to 1+$. I have no idea how much can be said with elementary methods.

The prime number theorem gives even stronger statements than this, for example it implies that there is a prime between $n$ and $(1 + \varepsilon) n$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$ and sufficiently large $n$ (where "sufficiently large" depends on $\varepsilon$).

By a result of Jitsuro Nagura, there is always a prime in both $\left[ {n,\frac{6}{5}n} \right]$ and $\left[ {\frac{5}{3}n,2n} \right]$, provided $n\ge 25$.

What do you mean by "the prime $q$ between $p$ and $2p$"?

Chebyshev's original proof of Bertrand's postulate already showed that
$$
cx + O(\sqrt x) \le \sum_{p\le x} \log p \le \frac{6c}5 x + O(\sqrt x)
$$
with $c = \log \left(2^{7/15} 3^{3/10} 5^{1/6} \right) \approx 0.921292$ and thus $\frac{6c}5 \approx1.10555$. Since the ratio of these two constants is $\frac65<2\big/\frac32<\frac32$, this already showed that all intervals of the form $[x,\frac32x]$ and $[\frac32x,2x]$ contain primes once $x$ is sufficiently large.
In 1952, Nagura established the explicit statement that there is always a prime between $n$ and $\frac65n$ once $n\ge25$. This and a little calculation show that for odd primes $p$, the only intervals of the form $(p,\frac32p)$ that don't contain a prime are $(3,\frac32\cdot3)$ and $(7,\frac32\cdot7)$, while the only interval of the form $(\frac32p,2p)$ that doesn't contain a prime is $(\frac32\cdot5,2\cdot5)$.
By now we have much better explicit bounds for constants $\delta$ such that every interval of the form $(x,(1+\delta)x)$ contains a prime once $x$ is sufficiently large in terms of $\delta$.

One question: It follows that $\sum_{x<p\leq \frac{3x}{2}}\log p\geq \frac{3c}{10}x+O(\sqrt{x})>0$ for large $x$. Hence there exists a prime $p$ such that $x<p\leq \frac{3x}{2}$. This is how we prove it, right?

Yes—if there were no primes, the sum would equal $0$.

Thanks! Now it makes sense.
